# Mysql master-master replication

Tags: replication, mysql

I have to try out a master-master replication for a database of four tables. Both the master can write at once, but they would not be updating the same rows of a table and the insertions will also be collision free. The replication should be asynchronous
Is this behaviour possible to implement? If so, do I have to write my own code to manage replication or can mysql's existing replication protocol manage this.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being we have dropped this idea, but if someone is looking for a similar solution, I found some useful links over internet...

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/05/mysql-master-master-replication-manager-released/
http://www.simplicidade.org/how-to/mysql-master-master/
http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?144,235807,235807

http://crazytoon.com/2008/02/29/mysql-how-do-you-set-up-mastermaster-replication-in-mysql-centos-rhel-fedora/

Hope it helps.